# Building Boost 1.75 Issue in CentOS7 with an Already Installed C++11 Compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost, centos7

I am trying to build `boost` 1.75 in CentOS7.

`gcc` and `C++` were updated to version 9.3.1 and c++14, respectively with the following shell scripts.

**script_update_gcc.sh**

```
sudo yum -y install centos-release-scl
sudo yum -y install devtoolset-9-gcc*
source scl_source enable devtoolset-9
gcc --version
# gcc (GCC) 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)
```

**script_update_c++.sh**

```
sudo yum -y install centos-release-scl-rh
sudo yum-config-manager --enable centos-release-scl-rh
sudo yum -y install devtoolset-9
source scl_source enable devtoolset-9
```

The script that I am using to build `boost` from source is as follows.

```
wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.75.0/source/boost_1_75_0.tar.gz
tar -xzf boost_1_75_*
cd boost_1_75_*
sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/opt/boost 
sudo ./b2 install --prefix=/opt/boost --with=all
```

However, I receive the following error message

```
A C++11 capable compiler is required for building the B2 engine.
Toolset 'cxx' does not appear to support C++11.

** Note, the C++11 capable compiler is _only_ required for building the B2
** engine. The B2 build system allows for using any C++ level and any other
** supported language and resource in your projects.


You can specify the toolset as the argument, i.e.:
    ./build.sh gcc

Toolsets supported by this script are:
    acc, clang, como, gcc, intel-darwin, intel-linux, kcc, kylix, mipspro,
    pathscale, pgi, qcc, sun, sunpro, tru64cxx, vacpp
```

I tried `./build.sh gcc` but the file does not exits in the source folder. I also tried adding the `gcc` version to the boostrap which did not work either.

```
sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/opt/boost --with-toolset=gcc-9.3.1
```

As my last resort, I tried `clang` and it did not help either and gave me the exact same error as above:

```
./bootstrap.sh toolset=clang cxxflags="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++"
```

Could someone kindly help me out? I already have `c++` and `gcc` updated to very recent versions and I don't know why `boost` complains about not having a c++11 capable compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Your extra "script_update_c++.sh" installs a gcc 4.8 to /usr/bin. I think that may be interfering.

Try

```
hash -r
which gcc
gcc --version
```

(Also which `g++`) to find out what is being picked up by your path.

If it reports the GCC 4.8 then in all likelihood you simply executed the scripts in subshells, rather than sourcing them. That doesn't work because

```
source scl_source enable devtoolset-9
```

sets environment variables for the ***current shell***. So either, issue that on its own, or run the scripts by sourcing them.

Comment: For demo [Download](https://gist.github.com/sehe/bc93b01cc17452030c944fa2a2464b43/archive/c05408b32deb7e625ca7f9515505427b4245c788.zip) this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sehe/bc93b01cc17452030c944fa2a2464b43) to test using `docker build .`